# Knockout validation error class on input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, knockout.js

I'm fairly new to Knockout and I'm encountering some issues when validating my form.

**HTML**

```
<input data-bind="value: naam" type="text" name="naam" id="naam" placeholder="Naam" required />
<input data-bind="value: email" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required pattern="@" />
```

**Knockout**

```
var OrderInfo = function(){
   var self = this;

   self.naam = ko.observable().extend({
       required: "true",
       minLength: 6
   });

   self.email = ko.observable().extend({
       required: "true",
       email: { 
           message: "Gelieve een geldig e-mail adres op te geven.", 
           params: true 
       }
   });
};
```

**Problems**

1) When I enter less than 6 chars at "naam", I get the message `Please enter at least 6 characters.`. Yet the class `valid` is given to the element. The e-mail input field gets the error class as it should. 
2) When I log whether OrderInfo is valid, I always get true, even though I get the error messages;

```
self.OrderInfo = ko.validatedObservable(self.orderInfo);
console.log("Valid: " + self.OrderInfo.isValid());
```

I have configured ko.validation like this;

```
ko.validation.configure({
   errorElementClass: 'error',
   decorateInputElement: true,
   decorateElementOnModified: true,
});
```

Why is this working for the e-mail field but not the other fields? (I've only posted 1 other field but I got more, same issue for all.) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of the validation plugin are you using (nuget,cdnjs,github)?

Comment: As far as I know I'm using the latest version from https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/tree/master/Src

Comment: Can you maybe create a repro jsfiddle? Because here it working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/gqxzt8g9/

Comment: The correct version https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: Have a look at this, http://jsfiddle.net/e3xszun3/ If you want to try using ko.validation.group

Answer (score 2):

Issue resolved. The problem was in my HTML. When marking up my form I accidently used the same ID twice.

Stupid mistakes take the longest to find... Thanks for trying to help out!